# when trying to install ubuntu or other linux, lose power to mouse and keyboard

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, mouse

I have this old computer "Compaq Presario SR1603WM Desktop PC" and im attempting to install linux on it. I have currently tried linux mint 17.1, mint 17, ubuntu 14.04, ubuntu 12.10(i think thats it) and lubuntu. Every time i put in the dvd to install, it gets to the very first starting screen that lets me select if i would like to try ubuntu, or install it. Both my keyboard and mouse work during this stage, however as soon as i choose one of the options i lose all power to both of them.

When it boots into the OS if i choose to try instead of install, it boots up and im unable to use mouse or keyboard at all. No lights are on. it appears to be all USB devices that are not working. I have installed various versions of linux in the past and haven't ever ran into this issue.Thanks very much for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I know of a workaround, but I cannot guarantee this very old pc won't have other problems later.  Install the os to the hard drive of that pc using a different computer, then when you reconnect that hard drive to your very old PC, it will very likely appear to operate the mouse and keyboard correctly.